# аргумент типа "WCHAR *" несовместим с параметром типа "const char *" !strcmp

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста

Ошибка:

> аргумент типа "WCHAR *" несовместим с параметром типа "const char *" !strcmp

```cpp
uintptr_t GetModuleBase(const char* modName) {
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, proc);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
            if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry)) {
                do {
                    if (!strcmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                    {
                        CloseHandle(hSnap);
                        return (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    }
                } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
            } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну и что вам не понятного в ошибке?

Comment: Я повторить не могу; проблемы при компиляции VC++ 2019 есть, но не эта. Как в режиме unicode, так и в обычном `char`..